# Consumer SSD on Server only to host OS, MS office, antivirus, accounting software

Tags: ssd

I have a IBM (Lenovo) System x3500 M4 Server with 16gb 2x 1TD hdd with 20 Terminals Think Clients for remote access at my office which was installed last year in May, replaceing 15 Desktops for team of 20 People. We don't use to many softwares apart from Accounting software, MS Office for emails, date entry, excel sheets, etc, basic back office work, Anti-Virus & Browsers.

Recently upgrade the RAM from 16GB to 32GB

I have install 2 hdd on the server, 1st for OS and primary softwares. 2nd all date fed into the server by users, emails, downloads, etc.

I would like to know if it will be feasible / right decision to use Consumer Grade SSD for "Hosting OS & Primary use software only", hardly any writing of data as all data will be store in the 2nd HDD only.

Will the Consumer Grade SSD suffice or i will have to buy Enterprise Grade SSD ??

Answer (score 3):

They will totally suffice. The most action they ever see is patch day. They likely will last many many years over the expected lifespan.

Comment: Isn't it likely that the OS disc also hosts swap, or whatever MS calls it?  That might be quite a lot busier.

Comment: Yes and no. Point being that if you run a multi application server in the year 2016 you will NOT use swap a lot. Extensive swap use is a sign of the server being overloaded..

Comment: That's fair enough, though I still configure swap on everything, because I've had too many servers die at the hands of the OOM-killer when something unexpected came along and ate up memory.  It was more that I thought the issue should be addressed, than that it was a show-stopper.  +1 from me, anyway!

Comment: Oh, i never said that. But you will not rely on swap space instead of memory ;)